# What features did the first version of Stack Overflow have?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-history

You could add, answer, and upvote questions.

What else could you do?

Was the reputation system already present in the first release? Did it give you editing and other privileges or did it only keep a count?

What other things did it have and not have?

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20080915103343/http://stackoverflow.com/, [timeline](https://stackexchange-timeline.webflow.io)

Comment: That would have been a great answer if capable of answering the specific question. The aim is not to know what it looked like, or when new developments appeared, but rather what features, what functionality, it had at launch. Thank you regardless.

Comment: Someone (independent, unbiased) ought to write the history of Stack Overflow. Perhaps it already exists?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) perhaps.

Comment: @Norbert seems kind of broad. It had tags, questions, answers, flagging, voting, badges. Many things worked differently e.g. high rep users as well as moderators could see (some) flags.

Comment: @RobertLongson, that's an actual answer to the question. The question is as narrow as possible for the purpose, the purpose being knowing what all the functionality of the first version was. Your link does not include that information, only the changes after the first version. If you could please move your answer to the answer section and away from the comment, and make it a bit more exhaustive (you're probably half way to a reasonably complete answer), I and future readers would appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

There is no definite list and it is unlikely any of the people involved back at the time are going to preserve that list for history.

However, you can do most of the research for that yourself. The podcasts from 2008 are still available on [the blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/podcast/page/22/) and they discuss at length what the initial platform would look like. On MSE there is a tag [SO History](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/so-history) that might have specific info on some of the details.

Other sources you might use is the blog of Joel Spolsky, for example [The Stack Overflow age](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2018/04/06/the-stack-overflow-age/) and of course Jeff Atwood, aka [Coding Horror](https://blog.codinghorror.com/).

Comment: Some of us are old enough to (mostly) remember, though...

Comment: @CodyGray sure, if you want to chip in I'm happy to make this answer community wiki and have all these old an ancient relics contribute to oral history ....